# How to make a thread wake up and suspend for 500ms continuously in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I am using multiple threads in my program. I want a specific thread to be waken up after 500ms. How can I do that without using a usleep(500)?

Comment: usleep is the only sane way to do this. What's your problem with using this?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But can we do it based on the system time elapsed or something?

Comment: Hope it may useful to you.  http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

Comment: Thanks. gettimeofday() worked.

Comment: In Windows you would `WaitForSingleObject` on the "kill me" event that your caller can set to tell your thread to finish. You should use a similar method. Threads that are asleep with no way of terminating them other than asking the kernel to purge the thread object is bad program design.

Comment: Why not with `usleep`?

Answer (score 2):

The socket API like select can be used as a timer.

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 500;
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
```

You may need this choice.

Comment: Can you show how to use *select* to "make a thread wake up and suspend for 500ms continuously" per the question?

Comment: @ringø, It is confused what 'make a thread' mean. Maybe the question is about sleep. the thread can sleep itself using select.

Comment: Sorry for the confuison.

Answer (score 0):

***clock_nanosleep*** is the POSIX compliant version to sleep for an interval on a high resolution clock, see man page, for example on http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_nanosleep for details.